# Some questions about $S^n$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, lie-groups, complex-geometry

I have some questions about the $n$-sphere:

I know that for $n=0,1,3$, $S^n$ forms a Lie group and I also know why it's true, but why is it not the case for other $n$?

I have the same question for the $n$-spheres admitting an almost complex structures $(n=2,6)$. Is there a general reason to conclude it doesn't have one  for any other $n$?

And finally, (this is a homework question):

Can $S^4$ have a Lorentz metric?

Comment: Lorentz metrics come equipped with a notion of `timelike'.  This means you can find a continuously-varying 1-dimensional subspace of every tangent space.  If you had such a thing, it would tell you something about the Euler Characteristic of $S^4$.  This is usually called the Poincare-Hopf Index Theorem.

Comment: Looking into that, Ryan, thank you.

Comment: So I found $\chi (S^4)=2$, does that mean it doesn't admit a Lorentzian metric? Since otherwise it would be $0$, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

The smooth manifold underlying a Lie group is always parallelizable, and the only spheres which are paralellizable are those of dimension $1$, $3$ and $7$.

On the other hand, the third cohomology group of a compact Lie group is never zero, so that excludes the possibility that $S^7$ be a Lie group.

As for complex structures, see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25557/references-on-almost-complex-structures-on-spheres)

Comment: Neither of the two results I mention in the first two paragraphs is obvious, by the way (thaat Lie groups are parallelizable is easy, though). The first one is a theorem of Milnor and Kervaire, and the second one follows from the description of compact Lie groups as (products of tori by semi-simple compact groups) divided by finite abelian subgroups, and the result that semisimple simple compact Lie groups have non-trivial $\pi_3$.

Comment: I see, I was just curious about it. I also looked online and didn't find many things other than it being known. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Concerning the complex structures, there is a $K$-theoretic proof for the cases $n > 4$ and $n \neq 6$. Then in the case $n=4$ usually one does another argument. This case I think is actually much easier. Assume $S^4$ where almost complex. Then you can compute the first Pontryagin class in terms of chern classes and get a contradiction (the pontryagin class vanishes, but the second chern class is the euler class, so cannot be evaluated to zero).

Comment: "On the other hand, the third cohomology group of a compact Lie group is never zero", what about $S^1$?

Comment: I should have said simply connected.